# Using subjunctive following it is intended that

Tags: subjunctives

As far as I know, there are some specific verbs, nouns, and adjectives that subjunctive can only be used with. Wanted to know is this a fix rule, that is, really isn't it possible to use other things in the form of subjunctive? My question concerns "It is intended that":

> It is intended that the new method be able to address the previously mentioned shortcomings.

Many thanks

Comment: *It is attempted that* is not correct English.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks peter for picking up on this. What's another word to be used instead that conveys the same meaning? I mean sth just instead of attempted that.

Comment: *It is aimed that* isn't correct English either, How about *It is intended that*?

Comment: @PeterShor This one is much better, but I'm curious to know whether there isn't really something with the same meaning as try or effort to substitute it for attempt?

Comment: Why are you even using "It is intended"? This is simpler: The new method is intended to address the previously mentioned shortcomings. And it is less cumbersome.

Comment: Aren't you trying to use the best possible English?

Comment: It was just that I wanted to somehow use this grammar in my text to get included with more grammar forms. Again, many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "intend", (here in the form "It is intended that...") is one of the (rare) cases that can trigger the subjunctive.

With other verbs (It is aimed ... or It is attempted ...)  don't licence a content clause "that ...", and you can't use the subjunctive.

More generally, avoid the subjunctive, if possible. It usually isn't the clearest way to express an idea.

> We intend for the new method to be able to address the shortcomings of the old method.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer

Comment: It is attempted is not idiomatic here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid expressions like "it is intended" when it is not needed.

It is intended that the new method be able to address the previously mentioned shortcomings. =

**The new method is intended** to address the previously mentioned shortcomings.

Usage: [Something]  is intended to address [something else]

When do you need It is intended?

Example:
This game is well designed for this age group. It is intended *for* adolescents (over 13 years of age) and not small children.

Comment: Sorry for the delay to notice the answer and so many thanks for your favor.